# Markov optimal stopping time infite horizon

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stopping-times

I would like to show the following statement:

Let $\{X_t:t\geqslant 1\}$ be a Markov chain, with finite states $S$ and transition probabilies $p_{ij}, i,j\in S$. Let $S_r$ and $S_t$ its recurrent and transient states. Let $g: S \to\mathbb R^+$ such that $g(s) = 0, \forall s \in S_r$. Let $T$ be the set of stopping times over $τ = 1,2,3,\ldots$ that is $τ\in T $ is a random variable, its values are in $\mathbb N$, and $\{τ = t\}\in\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_t)$ for each $t\in\mathbb N$.

Given an initial value $X_1 = i$ let's define the optimal stopping problem as $v^*(i)$ such as 
$$v^*(i) = \sup\{E_i[g(Xτ)] : τ ∈T\}$$
where $E_i$ is the expected value when the initial value of the chain equals $i$.

Let's prove that $v^*$ is the unique solution of the equation:
$$v(i) =\max \left\{g(i), \sum_{j} p_{ij} v(j)\right\}, \forall i \in S$$

where $v(i) = 0$, $i \in S_r$.

Moreover, the following assumption holds:
$v^* $ is the minimum solution of the inequality system: 
$$ v(i) \geq \max \{g(i),  \sum_{j} p_{ij} v(j)\}.$$

My approach:
The equality to show reminds me the Wald–Bellman equation. There are some results regarding the Wald–Bellman equation and harmonic functions but i'm not sure how to show the uniqueness of the function. Furthermore, the Wald–Bellman results do not remark that $v(i) = 0, i\in S$.

Comment: are you sure you wrote this correctly?  You have $g: S \to\mathbb R^+$ where evidently $\mathbb R^+ = \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$  but then say $g(s) = 0, \forall s \in S$ which means with respect to the chain $g$ is the identically zero function.  Presumably you meant for $s \in S_t$ or $s \in S_r$.

Comment: @user8675309, i meant $s \in S_r$, i edited the post. Thanksfor your comment.

Comment: what sorts of tools do you have at your disposal here? Some basic ideas from real analysis help a lot as does method of relaxations... If you divide out the maximal g(i), negate and add one, this looks like the method of relaxations (e.g. for dirichlet problem)-- where for each transient state $i$ you look at a monotone non-decreasing sequence bounded above by 1 so a limit exists and that limit is the equality case.  Method of relaxations is nicely described in the free Doyle and Snell "Random Walks and Electric Networks" https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/walks/walks.pdf